# Why am I receiving "Cannot find 'performSegueWithIdentifier' in scope" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am writing my application in Swift. Here is the `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if !self.check_file() {
            print("Missing file to read")
            performSegueWithIdentifier("missingfileViewController", sender: nil)
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Here is `check_file()` function:

```
func check_file() -> Bool {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        return fileManager.fileExists(atPath:"/Applications/Readfile.app/Contents/Resources/textfile/readthis.txt") 
      
        
    }
```

I'm receiving this error `Cannot find 'performSegueWithIdentifier' in scope`.
Can anyone help me with this? Great thanks
**EDIT**: I have even tried to use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`, but another error comes up: `Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'performSegueWithIdentifier'`

Comment: You are using old syntax. New syntax is : ```performSegue(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>, sender: <#T##Any?#>)```

Comment: you mean ```performSegueWithIdentifier``` has been removed from Swift?

Comment: try like this self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "missingfileViewController", sender: self), I think the one which you are using is outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "missingfileViewController", sender: self)
```

try this